Why saving tags with spatie/laravel-tags data have diffrent slug and type fields?
Reading how to work with spatie tags in laravel 11 app
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-tags/v4/basic-usage/using-tags manually
I have installed spatie/laravel-tags 4.7 package
Saving tags I use method :
$article->syncTags($this->selectedTags, 'article');

But saved data have different format I added in seeder when inited the app :
Tag::findOrCreate(['film'], 'article');

I see different value in slug and type fields :

Looks lke with syncTags method slug and type fields are filled in different ways ?
What is wrong and how to fix it ?

You need to use syncTagsWithType() method, as $article->syncTagsWithType($this->selectedTags, 'article');

Use the syncTagsWithType, ex:
$article->syncTagsWithType($this->selectedTags, 'secondType');

